# quitting app will not destroy data

Tags: android, google-maps

I load my app on phone. work with it then quit the app and start again. but it keeps some data from previous time! How? how can I not get those data. I am starting the app from scratch again. and in my code there is destroy function. what should I put so that every time I get whole fresh data

Comment: " it keeps some data".  What data?

Comment: for example I change some marker's position and I redraw some other based on that position. when I start again the app it redraws the other marker based on previous saved data..

Comment: Then this is normal and how apps should behave. If you want the behaviour to be different, then please read the documentation for the "Activity Lifecycle" and describe what you are trying to do.  Remember that users expect apps to be in the same state when the return to them.

Answer (score 0):

"Quitting the app" might not always destroy the app. Maybe it keeps active in memory and resumes instead of starts again.
Try cleaning up "the data" in the onPause() or onStop() lifecycle method.